# How do I get my Android Application to have this part of the user interface?

Tags: java, android

I want to add this to my user interface, i'm new to Android, so please be kind with the terminology :):
[image]

How do I make sections for the "SearchBox" and the "Btns"?

Thank you.

Comment: Any good [android UI tutorial](http://google.com/?q=android+ui+tutorial) will teach you what you need to know. For the map, look up a tutorial on using the google maps api with android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're new to Android, the best way to learn it is to look at documentation and their examples. For your simple purpose, I would take a look at this `LinearLayout` [document](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html).

In your case, the two different Views you need is `EditText` for the search bar and `Button` for, of course, the buttons. It may be helpful in your case to use the `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` tags for the "bars". The row of buttons should be in their own `LinearLayout` which you can orient in a horizontal direction, then put it inside the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Great answer, makes a lot of sense. I understand all the layouts pretty much but I thought there might be some sort of code that sorts that out for you? Like for Android 3.0 - ActionBar()? But i'm coding in Android 2.2, is there any code that would do something like ActionBar()? I don't find it a problem doing this method, just enquiring.

Comment: I think I know what you're talking about. `ActionBar` is probably something for Android 3.0 because it's quite useful for tablet interfaces. The closest thing I can vaguely think of that I've used before for a similar style is a ButtonBar. It's not really view, but just a style you can add to make the bars stand out. Check here for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3795949/394933.