# Why "Buttons in button bars should be borderless" in Android API Level 15?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm developing an application for Android and I recently changed the API level target from 8 to 15, and now Eclipse is warning me when the `Buttons` are inside `Linear Layouts` or `Table Rows`.

The same doesn't happen when the `Button` is in a `Relative Layout`.

The warning says:

> Buttons in button bars should be borderless; use
>   style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle" (and
>   ?android:attr/buttonBarStyle on the parent)

I can get rid of the warning by following the suggestion or even by suppressing it, but I'm interested to know why this now? What's wrong with bordered buttons?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/buttons.html

Comment: @Math did you found solution?

Comment: @jaimin well, I little reluctantly I ended up by adapting my layout to look better with the new directives from Android. I had to spend some time on that because at first it really didn't look nice. Time I didn't want to invest at that time mainly because I didn't get why I should do so. After all the result is more professional and longstanding, this is why I fell like it's always preferable to understand the root cause of the warning and fix it than just to make it stop through some menu option.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The borderless buttons are for cohesiveness of design throughout the android platform. It's recommended you follow the guidelines so that the user feels that your app is native and does not stick out like a sore thumb, but there are many cases where it just doesn't make sense, like if it makes your app look unprofessional. If that is the case, you may want to turn off the warning.

To turn off the warning, go to the project properties -> Android Lint Preferences. Search for "border" or "ButtonStyle" and change the severity to ignore on the bottom right.

You can also do this in Eclipse preferences for all projects.

For Android Studio Users:

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Android Lint. Search for "borderless" and uncheck or change the severity.

Comment: Well, this will get rid of the warnings, but I'm still curious of why android is warning us to use borderless buttons. I mean, is this some new `best practice` advice that I should be practicing and I'm not? Also, the button get pretty ugly if I follow their advice. I just don't understand the warning.

Comment: I didn't realize you moved the comment to the answer. I believe this do answer my question now and is the correct answer. Sorry to take so long to accept it.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the real question. Why was the warning there really?

Comment: I don't think these guidelines apply anymore. If you look at the Settings / Apps in Android, you will see the Uninstall/Force Stop buttons are centralized and have margins in between them.

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree with this recommendation and the warning.  I will style my buttons however I please, thank you very much.

Answer (score 25):

## Here is another simple way to get rid of it.

The compiler is trying to tell you to set the style of the button. So simply add the following style for the Android default borderless style and the error will be gone.

```
<Button
    ...
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
```

Here is the proof

[image]

Comment: Adding that removes any styling the buttons had, leaving a transparent button with white text - is there a way around that?

Comment: @JamesF the idea is to have a style defined for each button. If you already have one, use yours and the warning will also be gone

Comment: This also helps when you use the background property for styling the button instead of the style property. The value I used to get rid of the warning was "@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless".

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding that style to ALL buttons which were ONLY elements in some linerar layout gave buttons without any borders. After adding style also to the layout I got buttons separated with small edges exsacly like in some epements of my (4.1.2) android interface eg. like in dialog possitive/negative buttons. It worked correctly. Standard Holo buttons are ugly but with that styles they look "professional";-)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to fix it " style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/> "
but if your emulator is too old then that problem can occur aswell.Try to change your emulator Pixel 6 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the warning for the particular code, simply add `tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"` to the button.

```xml
<...Layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
...


<Button
...
tools:ignore="ButtonStyle"
```

(I am not sure what was possible back then when the question was asked.)