# Bottom menu bar in android

Tags: android

I have seen some iOS apps using menu bar at button and I want to implement it myself.

I was thinking of using `Button`s in a `Linearlayout` as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795923/bottom-button-bar-in-android) post. But I was wondering if there is better solution or built in custom view for implementing this. Can anyone suggest me bettter way of doing it?

Comment: [Android guidelines say don't do this.](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html)

Comment: @panini I am aware that this is not the recommended way of doing it. But I am developing this app for multiple platform so I have to be consistent with the design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using *FragmentTabHost* with a *Button* inside a *FrameLayout*. Cheapest way I imagine. It's your choice.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I will definitely try this way