# Bottom Panel in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to design an app with a layout that will roughly look like this (don't mind the color):

[image: This is what I'm trying to do]

How can I achieve something like that? I'm thinking of using a `CardView` for that bottom panel (I don't know what it's really called).
Furthermore, I want to hide it (animating it) when the use scrolls on the content. I have tried many codes but they won't work so I won't put them here anyway (like what's suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795923/bottom-button-bar-in-android)). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you figure that out?

Answer (score 3):

Whenever I have a question along the lines of "How do I do this neat UI thing I saw once?", I always start by checking out wasabeef's amazing [UI library collection](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui). In your case I might start by looking at bottomsheet or AndroidSweetSheet.

Comment: I've checked those two but they're slightly not fit for what I am trying but still, thanks for pointing me to that collection.

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: https://github.com/drxeno02/androidprojects-book2-slidingdrawer