# How to implement this material design feature? (Button floating above keyboard)

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design

Please check this screenshot

[image]

How to add buttons like this in android. Is there a library for it or what is it called?

Please note that when keyboard is hidden, this button takes up the space for navigation buttons.

Another question: How to change the size of the blue app bar when keyboard appears or hides?

**UPDATE : ** I can implement a similar layout using borderless buttons in frame layout and setting the gravity to bottom. Then I used android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
 in the manifest file to make it work with keyboard hide/unhide. Still these buttons are not taking the space of navigation buttons. Also still need guidance for change app bar size on keyboard appear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

1- [AppIntro](https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro)

2- [AppTour](https://github.com/vlonjatg/AppTour)

Comment: I'll try it and check if buttons stay on the top of the keyboard. Thanks for pointing to these libs

Comment: I think that  AppIntro is the best. you can put a custum fragment in the  slider.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would say that the button is not related in any way with they keyboard. I bet it's just a button inside a `FrameLayout` with the `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` property set.

Comment: when I set the layout_gravity of FrameLayout to bottom, then the button appears at bottom but it doesn't stay on the top of the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

It is a borderless button placed in a container(probably `LinearLayout`)
container itself is called `buttonBar`

> **Borderless button**
>
> One design that can be useful is a "borderless" button. Borderless
>   buttons resemble basic buttons except that they have no borders or
>   background but still change appearance during different states, such
>   as when clicked.
>
> To create a borderless button, apply the borderlessButtonStyle style
>   to the button. For example:
>
> ```
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/button_send"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:text="@string/button_send"
>     android:onClick="sendMessage"
>     style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />
> ```

[sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3795949/1529129) for button bar

> ```
> <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/footer" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" style="@android:style/ButtonBar">
>
>     <Button android:id="@+id/saveButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:text="@string/menu_done" />
>
>     <Button android:id="@+id/cancelButton" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"
>         android:text="@string/menu_cancel" />
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Effect of everything else collapsing and this button bar being at top op keyboard can be achieved by keeping your entire view except buttonBar in a scroll view.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a reference. Insert your layout inside ScrollView.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

           <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lines="1"
                />

           </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="button"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```