# Align Buttons in Linear Layout to the Bottom of the Screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="200dip"


     />
     <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tview_total"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Total Files Processed:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tview_success"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Successfully Processed:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tview_error"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="right"
            android:text="Error Processing:" />

    </LinearLayout>


  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llBottomContainer2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="5dp" >       
         <Button
            android:id="@+id/proceed2"
            style="@style/btn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_sel"
            android:text="Proceed" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to align the Button on the bottom of the screen.I tried setting

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
```

Does not work.What i'm i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping that in a RelativeLayout?

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried .. but it seems i need to set the stuff like `to left of ` ,`to right of ` for all views...and there is no option to set it for Linear Layouts within Relative Layout.

Comment: No, you put a LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout. The buttons are outside the LinearLayout, next to it, within the RelativeLayout and aligned to the bottom

Comment: @cricket_007 Do you mind posting it as an answer.. with code edits.

Comment: Hard to do that on my phone. Just drag and drop some layouts around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bottom button bar in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795923/bottom-button-bar-in-android)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llBottomContainer2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:padding="5dp" >
```

Comment: just made height to fill_parent. but i must say that please use match_parent instead of fill_parent to make your compatible with newer version of android.

Answer (score 1):

try this layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="200dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tview_total"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Total Files Processed:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tview_success"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Successfully Processed:" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tview_error"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="Error Processing:" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llBottomContainer2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/proceed2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Proceed" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

where `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` is key parameter.

Happy coding..

Comment: Great .. Thanks... But the Button style is nit coming even after adding `style="@style/btn"`

Comment: that is totally different question. any how what kind of style do you have?

Comment: I have upvoted your answer.. but the other answer works well for me.. so choosing that.Thanks...

Answer (score -2):

```html
android:gravity="bottom"
```

Then make the gravity of layout or your button to the bottom

Comment: layout_alignParentBottom is invalid parameter for LinearLayout